# How to get Windows 7 back on the grub menu list?

Tags: grub2

I installed two OS in my computer, 10.04 and Windows 7, after some mistakes, there is no Windows 7 loader in the grub list, that is to say, I can't enter Windows 7, so what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo update-grub` from within Ubuntu. It should auto-detect Windows 7.

Comment: Please run "sudo os-prober" and include the output in your question. If it produces no output then please run boot info script: http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/ and add the contents of the RESULTS.txt to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) in Ubuntu.

---

### Installing Boot Repair

1. Open the Terminal, then type:

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
2. Press Enter.
3. Then type:

   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
4. Press Enter

### Using Boot Repair

Search for Boot Repair in the dash and launch it. Then click the "Recommended Repair" button and wait until it's finished.

---

Reboot. Is Windows 7 there again?